# R Shiny: Change uiOutput wrapper

Tags: html, css, r, shiny, uioutput

Every time I use renderUI (server side) and uiOutput (UI side) the html is wrapper by a **div**, how can I wrappe it by a **span** instead?

For example:

UI side:

```
tags$p(uiOutput("my_variable"))
```

Server side:

```
output$currentLev1 <- renderUI({return(input$my_variable)})
```

Result:

```
<div id="my_variable" class="shiny-html-output shiny-bound-output">my_variable</div>
```

Desired result:

```
<span id="my_variable" class="shiny-html-output shiny-bound-output">my_variable</span>
```

(simply change div by span)

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using argument `inline=T` creates a span instead of a div:

```
> args(uiOutput)
function (outputId, inline = FALSE, container = if (inline) span else div, 
    ...) 
NULL
```

and so:

```
> uiOutput("test", inline=T)
<span id="test" class="shiny-html-output"></span>
```